# Make a Debian Package (.deb) from a Qt Project

Tags: deb, qt, source-code

I did several projects on Qt Creator and I would like to distribute them in an installable format (in this case, Debian Packages).

**More info about my Qt installation (and my system):**

- Qt version 4.8.0 (32 bit)
- Qt Creator 2.4.1
- I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just made my package by following [tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html). I recommend running `qmake` to create the `Makefile`, so that you don't run into problems while executing `dpkg-buildpackage`.

---

**Steps**

Assuming you have already setup the `debian` directory in the source code,

1. Copy the source directory (where the `.pro` file is) to your Home directory and rename it to `yourProjectName_projectVersion`.
2. Open a terminal and execute `cd yourProjectName_projectVersion`.
3. Then, execute `dh_make -s -c gpl -e yourEmailAddress --createorig`
4. Finally, execute `dpkg-buildpackage`. You may get something like `error exit status 255`, if so, check that the `tar.xs` file in you Home folder matches the file requested by `dpkg-buildpackage` (check the last lines of the output of `dpkg-buildpackage` to find out what file wants).

---

If you seek an easier and faster way, you can use [Debreate](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/debreate-helps-you-create-debian-ubuntu.html) (I did not test it, so I cannot assure you that it will work).

I hope this helps anyone who wants to distribute their Qt project.

Comment: the link is broken, but accessible with  [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130330204129/http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html)

Comment: Any newer, more recent solution to this problem?